# Google Cloud Run - Secrets Volume Mount - update causes error mkdir file exists

Tags: gcloud, google-cloud-run, google-secret-manager

I have created a service with secrets volume mounted. The first run seems to work.
But when I try to update the service to update the docker image, it fails.

terminated: Application failed to start: volumefs(0, secret_volume_0): creating mount: mkdirall(/mnt/app/0/var/run/secrets/api/db_connection_name): mkdir /mnt/app/0/var/run: file exists

How is the update supposed to work?

Comment: Your post does not show how or what you are updating. An error message without details is not helpful.